Equivalent infinite series to Riemann Zeta function
I was studying the analytic continuation of Riemann Zeta function. There was this relationship given-
$$\zeta(s)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n[{1\over n^s}-{1\over(n+1)^s}]$$
For $\Re$(s)>1
I tried to understand it intuitively and I did.
For example I took $\zeta$(2) and this expression converted into
1($\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{4}$)+2($\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9}$)+3($\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}$)...=$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$
But I want to prove it rigorously.I tried to expand the expression but it didn't help.
The inner expression
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over n^s}-{1\over(n+1)^s}=1$$
We can conclude it from telescopic series of Zeta function.I don't know how to use this result in the proof also.

Fix a complex number $s$ with real part strictly greater than 1. Now, let $N$ be an arbitrary positive integer. Applying summation by parts we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{1}{n^s}}=\frac{1}{N^s}\sum_{n=1}^N{1}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{1}\right) \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}-\frac{1}{n^s}\right)},$$
and so, $$\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{1}{n^s}}=\frac{1}{N^{s-1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{n\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}-\frac{1}{n^s}\right)}.$$
Hence, the result follows by letting $N \to \infty$.
